# How can I troubleshoot OS sluggishness?

Tags: hardware, troubleshooting

I have a Dell G5 5590 (more specs listed below) which originally had Windows (10, I believe) installed on it.

I have tried to install multiple versions of linux OS (one at a time - no dual boot at all), but am met with a similar issue each time: it is slow to boot (~5 minutes) and is slow to even launch a single application (e.g., ~20-30 second to launch the Vivaldi browser with no other applications running).

I feel as though I should be getting *much* more performance out of this machine, but don't know where to begin. Any advice I can get to troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is other information that would be helpful to know.

Laptop Specs:

Software

| Item | Version |
| --- | --- |
| KDE Plasma Version | 5.25.5 |
| KDE Frameworks Version | 5.98.0 |
| Qt Version | 5.15.6 |
| Kernel Version | 5.19.0-46-generic (64-bit) |
| Graphics Platform | X11 |

Hardware

| Item | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Processors | 12 x Intel Core i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60Ghz |
| Memory | 15.3 GiB of RAM |
| Graphics Processor | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 |
| Manufacturer | Dell Inc. |
| Product Name | G5 5590 |

In addition, I'm hoping to use this machine to develop Unity games, so being able to effectively run both Unity and JetBrains Rider is a necessity for me. I'm open to trying new linux distros; I have previously tried Pop_OS! and "vanilla" Ubuntu.

Edit: Adding storage information

```
# lshw -class disk
  *-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
       vendor: Toshiba
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0D
       serial: 29IJPMZNT
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=fce34435-7d36-4f31-84b0-5bdf981922c5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

Comment: what storage option does the laptop have? HDD? M.2 NVMe 3X2? M.2 NVMe 3x4? M.2 Intel Optane? HDD & M.2?

Comment: I have a single HDD (1TB),

    # lshw -class disk
      *-disk                    
           description: ATA Disk
           product: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
           vendor: Toshiba
           physical id: 0.0.0
           bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
           logical name: /dev/sda
           version: 0D
           serial: 29IJPMZNT
           size: 931GiB (1TB)
           capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
           configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=fce34435-7d36-4f31-84b0-5bdf981922c5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096

Comment: Is it possible to replace that with an SSD? I know SSD's are faster than HDD's though, not sure a HDD would explain the 5 minute boot time! According to the specs on that laptop, it could have 2 x M.2 slots as well, even the M.2 3x2 one would outperform even an SSD - the M.2 3x4 would be even faster

Comment: I know the computer supports a SSD, but I don't have one to attempt a replacement. I am also not sure if that is the root of the issue, either. I don't remember having issues with boot time back when I _did_ use the Windows installation - I only noticed it after installing Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. it does seem particularly slow - if you boot a "live cd" (i.e. from USB) does it also take 5 minutes to boot? Also, S.M.A.R.T tools could show if there's any issue with the HDD

Comment: I will have to try a USB tomorrow - don't have the capability of creating one at this exact moment. Running a short smart test didn't indicate any issues - I'll have to run a longer one tomorrow as well. Thanks for the starting point for troubleshooting - I will report back when I have more details.

Comment: Check the logs, for example `/var/log/kern.log`. It includes timestamps and you can see if it is waiting for a long time for something to happen. For example, the wrong module could be used for a specific piece of hardware. With the log it should be a lot easier to see what takes so long.